# Assign Locally Stored jQgrid parameters to first call to server

Tags: jqgrid, lib.web.mvc

I have seen following [implementation of Localstorage](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage2_.htm) of settings and need to implement this. I have come across the code from line 243-247 that

```
            gridview: true,
            page: isColState ? myColumnsState.page : 1,
            search: isColState ? myColumnsState.search : false,
            postData: isColState ? { filters: myColumnsState.filters } : {},
            sortname: isColState ? myColumnsState.sortname : 'invdate',
            sortorder: isColState ? myColumnsState.sortorder : 'desc',
            rownumbers: true,
```

As you can see this is nice approach as it checks on first load if isColState is true then choose parameters accordingly however with Lib.Web.MVC helper I am not able to do this at server side and can only put integers and lists as provided. I am looking at [this wiki page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) and come across events like `LoadBeforeSend`, `beforeRequest` and `beforeProcessing` which may help me modify grid column model, its search and sort parameters and paging options etc before first request go out to server. After that it can simply keep updating local storage and so on. BeforeProcessing is not available in Lib.Web.Mvc library and I am not sure if there is an alternative.

Any ideas to solve this.

Comment: @tpeczek can you please see this when you get time.

Comment: Somehow I have missed this one, are you still looking for answer?

Comment: I will sit down to this tommorow and see if there is a nice way to do this with Lib.Web.Mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to achieve what you want with current functionality of Lib.Web.Mvc. The closest ready to use functionality is wrapper around jqGrid import/export configuration functionality. Please refer to this demo project for more details:

- [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC - Strongly typed helper](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/62741)

If you want, you can rewritte the code of JqGridHelper class in order to fit your needs.

If you think this would be a valuable addition to the helper, please describe how would you see the feature and drop me an issue [here](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic), I will be happy to work on it.

Comment: I have looked at it and I have hooked two client side functions `loadBeforeSend: "jsfunction",` and `beforeRequest:"jsfunction"` to accomodate for testing if stored items are available and hook them into post data (before request) and then show/hide columns, order them and modify colModel with new order (before send). This did the job for both import export and simply saving postData and column Model.